# Need a request-promise alternative that supports unGzip

Tags: node.js, express, http, axios, request-promise

It's been 3 days now, 3 days looking and trying different **alternatives of request-promise** (deprecated), So I really hope someone would be able to help me here.

I'm making my first scraping server app, So I was using request-promise bust since it got deprecated I'm looking for something else, But **I need it to support unGziping**, As you may know request-promise have this feature witch comes in handy when scraping a lot of data.

I liked axios & node-fetch but when I use 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br', All I get is some coded data that does even get decoded on some websites like : http://www.txtwizard.net/compression

So My Question Is : ***Is There A Way To Use Gzip with Axios or Node-Fetch ???***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`got`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) with `decompress: true`.

```
const { body } = await got('http://www.example.com', { decompress: true });
```

[`decompress`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got#decompress) defaults to `true` so you don't need to pass it.

Although `axios/fetch` should decompress by default, so maybe there's something else going on with your request.

You can always decompress it yourself using `zlib` built-in module

Comment: thank you for your answer I tried that and it works fine. have a nice day!